Save metadata from QGIS directly to PostGIS database
When I save a layer in a geopackage in QGIS, the metadata is also saved. When I look at the layersettings in the geopackage, all metadata is visible.
However, when I import the layer into a PostGIS database, the metadata is not included.
Is there a way to save the metadata from QGIS to PostGIS?
